# Trying to write a small script edit in .bashrc : Close a terminal after opening a program

Tags: bash, linux-mint, i3

I recently changed my OS to Linux Mint, and have switched over to using the i3 window manager. To open files from terminal, I use xdg-open. This results in a file (.pdf, .txt, etc.) to be opened by a default selected application (if you want, you can open .txt files with Firefox). You can also just type "open whatever.ext" into the command line and it will work. The thing is, I would like to configure my .bashrc file so that the terminal window closes after running this command, or else I'm stuck with two windows for the price of one.

I know using dmenu (or rofi in my case) also opens applications, but I'm spending most of my time in terminal. It would just be really clean to go "open math_hw.pdf" and have the terminal be replaced by the PDF viewer, rather than me going [rofi -> pdf veiwer -> open new file -> select file] with the GUI.

Since I have never written any scripts before in my life, and googling for the past few hours has been in vain, I would appreciate any suggestions on how I should write the script.

I've tried `xopen() { xdg-open "$@" && exit; }` and writing a function

```
function op() {
  xdg-open $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown
}
```

both allow me to save the bash file with `source ~/.bashrc' in the terminal without giving any errors, but still don't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function, when added to your `.bashrc`, will launch xdg-open in the background and immediately exit the shell (which usually closes the terminal window).

```bash
op() {
    xdg-open "$@" &
    exit
}
```

Example usage case: You open a terminal and type `op my-file.pdf` at which point the terminal exits and whatever PDF viewer/editor you have configured opens. Unfortunately (maybe?), if it cannot figure out how to open the file, the terminal will still close.

**Important Note**: When you make changes to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, in order for the changes to take effect, you must either:

- Close your terminal window and start another one -OR-
- Run `. ~/.bashrc` in the terminal -OR-
- Run `exec $SHELL` in the terminal

Any one of these three actions will apply the changes.

Comment: This worked. I'd like to say I'm glad, but more upset that I've been using 'source ~/.bashrc' to save my edits. I got that from [the top answer of a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587109/how-can-i-launch-a-gui-program-from-a-terminal-but-close-the-terminal-once-its) to mine. Could you explain why 'source ~/.bashrc' did not work for me?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to literally replace the terminal with the new process, there's `exec` for that. Add something like this to your bashrc:

```
xopen() {
  exec xdg-open "$@"
}
```

And then a simple `xopen math_hw.pdf` will replace the terminal process with the PDF viewer process.

Comment: Thanks for replying,

I tried this and it still didnt work.

Just to make sure that im saving my changes and testing them correctly, my process for testing out edits in the .bashrc file is :

    - 1 - Edit .bashrc with new script and Save

    - 2 - In terminal no.1,  write 'source ~/.bashrc' 

   - 3 - Open terminal no.2 and try xdg-open (or whatever the alias/command im appending is)

     - 4 - If it doesnt work, close terminal no.2 and go back to .bashrc to try something different + save after

- 5 - enter source ~/.bashrc again

 - 6 -   Open terminal two again to test

Comment: Maybe you figured it out from the other comment but you want to make sure you're loading the new bashrc in the same shell where you're trying to run the command. You can generally check what your function is defined as with `type <function name>` and confirm that it contains your changes.

Comment: you development and "testing" process is approximately correct. Step 2 only affects the terminal where you execute that command. BUT because you have saved your `~/.bashrc` (in step 1), when you open a new terminal in step 3, it **IS** reading your improved file.  Again, step 5 is redundant OR eliminate step 6 and just try running your cmd in the step 5 window. `type <func_name>` is very good addition to your process. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Sorry i mixed up a couple steps in my process, I've spent way too long on this and my brain is fried. Basically, I had 3 terminal windows open to do these steps separately : Edit the bash file, apply the edits I made to shell, test out my edits. I'm guessing using `source ~/.bashrc' only applied the changes to the shell I wrote it in, so the terminal I used to test (even after I saved the file, and close/reopened the terminal because opening the file locked it) didnt have the changes applied.

Comment: @tjm3772 

Thankyou, you helped me confirm. I thought the way I was loading .bashrc would apply instantaneously everywhere. I will use `'type <func_name>` in the future to make sure my changes are set.